Unallocated space (ubuntu 22.04.04)
I just set up a small home server and when I looked at its total disk space it said 100G. So I took a quick look into lsblk and this was the output:
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                       7:0    0  63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2105
loop1                       7:1    0  63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2264
loop2                       7:2    0    87M  1 loop /snap/lxd/27037
loop3                       7:3    0    87M  1 loop /snap/lxd/28373
loop4                       7:4    0  40.4M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20671
loop5                       7:5    0  38.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21465
nvme0n1                   259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1               259:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               259:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3               259:3    0 950.8G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /

As you can see 950.8G of my total disk space are not allocated. Could somebody help me out here, because I don't really know what to do. Thanks!

You need t6o use LVM tools to manage it.

The disk space is allocated in Volume group. If you exec command vgs you will see it. If you want to use it you can create new logical volume with command vlcreate, then create filesystem and mount it (do not forget to update /etc/fstab). Or you can extend your root filesystem. The command you can use is lvextend. This command can extend also the filesystem for you.
